# jQuery button + and -

Tags: jquery, forms, dom, input

I need to create simple form with input and '-' and '+' button.. the initial value for input is for example 8 and minimum is 3 and maximum is 11.

The counter works only for the first time.

```js
(function() {

  $jsPassLength = $('#js-pass-length');
  value = $jsPassLength.val();

  $('.minus').click(function() {
    $jsPassLength.attr('value', value * 1 - 1);
  });

  $('.plus').click(function() {
    $jsPassLength.attr('value', value * 1 + 1);
  });

})();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0cbsgyac/)

Comment: Post your code in the question, not in a jsfiddle. Use a snipplet, it is just like the jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0cbsgyac/2/

Comment: Why the IIFE instead of `$(function() {});` to wait for the DOM to load?

Comment: I have a problem with format here, but I don't think it's reason for so bad rating :/

Comment: Yes, now it looks better.

Comment: Still why `(function{...})()` instead of `$(function() {...});` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply edit your JS like this:

```
$(function() {
  $jsPassLength = $('#js-pass-length');
  var value,
      min_value = 3,
      max_value = 11;

  $('.minus').click(function(){ 
    value = $jsPassLength.val();

    if (value > min_value) {
      $jsPassLength.attr('value',value*1-1);
    }
  });


  $('.plus').click(function(){ 
    value = $jsPassLength.val();

    if (value < max_value) {
      $jsPassLength.attr('value',value*1+1);
    }
  });
})();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0cbsgyac/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) and if I need to add maximum or minimum value?

Comment: If this solution worked for you please don't forget to accept it as the right answer. :)